# Linphone on Ubuntu 16.04 - Crashing?

Tags: 16.04, repository, sip, linphone

I am trying to get Linphone to work on an Ubuntu 16.04 x64 / x86 machine. I have added the following repository via the command:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linphone/release
> ```

And Linphone 3.9.1 was installed. **But - linphone appears to be crashing after I am closing it via the quit command**, I am getting a weird Segmentation fault error.

Is there any way I can install one of the latest available Linphone versions? (like 3.12 etc.)

Comment: Use the command line , type `linephonec` then `help` to see the available options

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the easiest way to install it is to use Flatpack:

1. Install Flatpak on Ubuntu

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install flatpak
   ```
2. Then install linphone 4.1.1 from Flatpak (only x86_64)

   ```
   flatpak --user install --from https://linphone.org/flatpak/linphone.flatpakref
   ```
3. Run Linphone from terminal

   ```
   flatpak run com.belledonnecommunications.linphone
   ```

or from menu.